# Append json files while iterating through for loop

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to iterate through some range of pages and save all of them into one json file, that is append page 2 to page 1 and page 3 to already appended page2 to page1.

```
for i in range(4):
    response = requests.post("https://API&page="+str(i))
    data = response.json()
    my_data = json.load(open( "data.json" ))
    my_data.update(my_data)
    json.dump(data, open( "data.json", 'w' ))
```

Basing on some answers from similar question I wrote something like that, but it overwrites instead of appending one page to another.

The json data structure is as follows:

[image]
ending with page number that increments every page.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is it that you are trying to achieve?**

You are overwriting the file `data.json` each time with the result of the response saved in the variable `data`.

Your code has 2 issues: you are updating a dictionary and you are overwriting a file. Any of the two could solve your problem, depending on what you want to achieve.

It looks like you instead want to save the contents of `my_data` like that:

```py
json.dump(my_data, open( "data.json", 'w' ))
```

Anyway, `my_data` will be a dictionary that gets its contents overwritten each time. Depending on the structure of `data`, this could not be what you want.

I'll explain better: if your structure is, for any page, something like

```json
{
    "username": "retne",
    "page": <page-number>
}
```

`my_data` will just be equal to the last `data` page.

Moreover, about the second issue, if you open the file in `'w'` mode, you will always overwrite it.
If you will open it in `'a'` mode, you will *append* data to it, obtaining something like this:

```json
{
    "username": "retne",
    "page": 1
}
{
    "username": "pentracchiano",
    "page": 2
}
{
    "username": "foo",
    "page": 3
}
```

but this is not a valid `.json` file, because it contains multiple objects with no delimiters.

Try being clearer about your intents and I can provide additional support.

Comment: My intention is to copy and save the data from one page into the data.json file, then go to the next page and append the page (second one) to the first one, so in the end I will have one file, but containing 2 pages. I forgot to specify that the API call allows me to specify delimiter, being either of  , ; ;END; !END!

Comment: Then read the JSON file and save it directly to the file using 'a' mode without reloading it from the file. There is no need for the my_data variable to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overwriting the contents of the `data.json` file on each iteration of the loop. This is because you are using the `'w'` mode when calling `json.dump`, which will overwrite the contents of the file.

To append the data to the file, you can use the `'a'` mode instead of `'w'` when calling `json.dump`. This will append the data to the end of the file, rather than overwriting the contents.

Like this

```
for i in range(4):
    response = requests.post("https://API&page="+str(i))
    data = response.json()
    my_data = json.load(open( "data.json" ))
    my_data.update(my_data)
    json.dump(data, open( "data.json", 'a' ))
```

Comment: doesn't work due to json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 158021